# c# wpf, binding value of property depending on the bool value

Tags: c#, wpf

Sorry for my bad english. I want to bind a `BorderBrush` of `ListBoxItem` depending on the bool value of object.
I have a `Directory` class, that has `IsForCopy` and `IsCutted` bool props.
So, if `IsForCopy` is true, then `BorderBrush` = Red, if `IsCutted` is true, then `BorderBrush` = Blue. How can I do this?

```
ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">
                    <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="SecondListBoxItem_MouseDoubleClick"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="What do I should type there?"></Setter>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a class that implements IValueConverter. Then in the convert method you can specify how you want to map a bool to a brush any way you want. And every binding has a converter attribute which you can set to this class that implemented IValueConverter.